# Inserir o valor de um count(*) numa variável no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, funções, trigger

Estou migrando do MySQL para o PostgreSQL e tentando criar a seguinte trigger:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verificaReservaQuarto()
RETURNS trigger
AS $$
    begin
        declare ocupado int;
declare consultaReserva int;
select count(*) into @consultaReserva from reserva_quarto R where R.dataSaida is null and R.dataEntrada is not null and new.idConsulta = R.idConsulta;
select count(*) into @ocupado from reserva_quarto R where R.dataSaida is null and R.dataEntrada is not null and new.idQuarto = R.idQuarto;
set new.dataSaida = null;
if (new.dataEntrada < now() or (@ocupado > 0) or (@consultaReserva > 0)) then
????????????????????????????
else 
return NEW;
end if;
 end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Porém, está dando o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*"
LINE 7: select count(*) into @consultaReserva from reserva_quarto R ...
               ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "count(*) into @consultaReserva from reserva_quarto R where R.dataSaida is null and R.dataEntrada is "
SQL state: 42601
Character: 149
```

Ali onde coloquei "???????????????" queria que não deixasse a inserção acontecer, pois na minha regra de negócio o quarto estaria ocupado.

Segue as tabelas usadas na trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE reserva_quarto (
dataEntrada timestamp not null,
dataSaida timestamp,
idConsulta INTEGER not null,
idQuarto INTEGER not null,
FOREIGN KEY(idQuarto) REFERENCES quartos (idQuarto),
FOREIGN KEY(idConsulta) REFERENCES consulta (idConsulta)
);

CREATE TABLE consulta (
idConsulta SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
prescricao VARCHAR(1000) not null,
dataConsulta timestamp not null ,
exame int not null,
idFuncGeral INTEGER not null,
idPaciente INTEGER not null,
idMedico INTEGER not null,
FOREIGN KEY(idMedico) REFERENCES medicos (idMedico)
);

CREATE TABLE quartos (
idQuarto SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
frigobar INTEGER not null,
TV INTEGER not null,
idAla INTEGER not null
);
```

Comment: Presumindo que sua trigger seja BEFORE então faça um `return NULL;`.

Answer (score 1):

Inverta a atribuição da variável com o `into`, dessa forma:

```
select into consultaReserva count(*) from reserva_quarto
```

Além disso, sua variável não tem o `@` no nome (isso é usado no `sql-server`), então não precisa disso

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "into"
LINE 7: select into consultaReserva count(*) from reserva_quarto R w...
               ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "into consultaReserva count(*) from reserva_quarto R where R.dataSaida is null and R.dataEntrada is "
SQL state: 42601
Character: 149

Comment: Ainda permanece o erro

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que seja uma trigger `BEFORE`, acho que seu código deveria ficar mais ou menos assim:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verificaReservaQuarto()
RETURNS SETOF TRIGGER AS 
$$
DECLARE
   ocupado BOOLEAN;
   consultaReserva BOOLEAN;
BEGIN

   PERFORM true
   FROM reserva_quarto r 
   WHERE r.dataSaida IS NULL 
   AND r.dataEntrada IS NOT NULL 
   AND NEW.idConsulta = r.idConsulta;

   consultaReserva = FOUND;

   PERFORM true
   FROM reserva_quarto r 
   WHERE r.dataSaida IS NULL 
   AND r.dataEntrada IS NOT NULL 
   AND NEW.idQuarto = r.idQuarto;

   ocupado = FOUND;

   NEW.dataSaida = null;

   IF NEW.dataEntrada < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP OR ocupado OR consultaReserva THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Não é possível fazer a reserva pois o quarto está ocupado.';
   ELSE
      RETURN NEW;
   END IF;

END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note que estou usando a variável `FOUND` e usando o comando `PERFORM` ao invés de `SELECT`. Fiz isso para otimizar a Consulta, já que não tem a necessidade de retornar o resultado do `COUNT`. Dessa forma retorna **true** se encontrou algum registro e **false** se não encontrou.

Aqui você encontra mais informações sobre quando e como usar o comando `PERFORM`: [Executing a Command with No Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT)